# How to open helm-imenu in existing buffer

Tags: helm

I'm using [`golden-ratio`](https://github.com/roman/golden-ratio.el) to automagically resize my buffers when I switch from one to another.

Say I have 2 buffers, my window is split vertically and active buffer is the one on the right. While activating `helm-imenu`, I would like to open results in an existing buffer on the left side (because those have a higher height than the ones below/above the active one).

I know of `C-t`, but I have to use it N times before it places `helm-imenu` buffer where I want.

Comment: Would you ping helm on github and report the answer ? I'm interested, thanks.

Comment: @Ehvince https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/emacs-helm/7ekAnBZ4YqA

Comment: @Ehvince thierryvolpiatto has replied and advice to look at `helm-split-window-default-side`. Not sure if I can make it work exactly like I described in my post but I'll definitely try in the coming week.

Comment: thanks. But isn't it a problem of golden-ration ? I think I have the behavior you describe by default.

Comment: Actually, the imenu buffer goes on the right when the active window is the left one, but it splits the window horizontally (what we don't want) when the active window is the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I want doesn't seem possible, that is, without adding some logic between change of active buffer.

What was bothering me was the lack of consistency. I am satisfied with:

```el
(setq
 helm-always-two-windows t
 helm-split-window-default-side 'left)
```

Which will open helm buffer on the left, full height and place the active buffer from which I invoked the helm menu on the right, full height as well. This is consistent and satisfies me, even though it doesn't directly answer my initial question.

Furthermore, one could play around with `helm-split-window-in-side-p`, `helm-always-two-windows` and `helm-split-window-default-side` for a different approach.